# Node using OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, server-side

I am interested in accessing my files (or just a folder) from my Google Drive - and having the access created (and granted) through server-side code.  I am not interested in logging in via the Browser.

I've created the OAuth Service Account, downloaded the p12 file and converted it to a .pem file..

BUT I can't see any examples in Node.js to do this.  I've seen a few examples on github that use OAuth to access Google Drive - but in fairness a lot of them do not work - which is really frustrating.

Google do not have a Node.js Client API Library for this.

I would love any help or pointing in the right direction if anyone has any thoughts.

Appreciate any help...

pandafinity

Answer (score 0):

This is the guidance and code that got me through it when integrating with the Google Analytics API in the same manner. It should work for Drive too:

https://gist.github.com/PaquitoSoft/4451865

Comment: Hi :) - Appreciate you saying but I couldn't really see the connection to Google Drive..so used google-oauth-jwt which has gotten me further but not to the end as yet.  Thanks for the thought :)

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten further:

Using the Node package "google-oauth-jwt" I've managed to authenticate my request and receive back an Access Token.

```
var googleAuth = require('google-oauth-jwt');

// obtain a JWT-enabled version of request
var request = googleAuth.requestWithJWT();
var TokenCache = googleAuth.TokenCache;
var tokens = new TokenCache();

tokens.get({
  // use the email address of the service account, as seen in the API console
  email: 'google-generated-email',
  // use the PEM file we generated from the downloaded key
  keyFile: 'pemfile.pem',
  // specify the scopes you wish to access
  scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly']
}, function (err, token) {
  console.log('Google API with JWT Request');
  console.log('---------------------------');
  console.log('The GoogleDrive Token is : ' + token);
});

googleAuth.authenticate({
  // use the email address of the service account, as seen in the API console
  email: 'google-generated-email',
  // use the PEM file we generated from the downloaded key
  keyFile: 'pemfile.pem',
  // specify the scopes you wish to access
  scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly']
}, function (err, token) {
  console.log('Google API: Authenticated');
  console.log('------------------------');
  console.log('The GoogleDrive Token is : ' + token);
});
```

Another thing the google-oauth-jwt allows is for a request to be sent using the JWT - but I am either low on coffee or do not really understand what comes back (probably the latter).

I used the following code to make the request:

```
  request({
  url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files',
  jwt: {
    // use the email address of the service account, as seen in the API console
    email: 'google-generated-email',
    // use the PEM file we generated from the downloaded key
    keyFile: 'pemfile.pem',
    // specify the scopes you wish to access - each application has different scopes
    scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly']
  }
}, function (err, res, body) {
    console.log(JSON.parse(body));
});
```

The Console.log produces the following:

```
   { kind: 'drive#fileList',
  etag: '"fk0AzBEIhUhhdZ8fZzKcL1hA5NE/oop8mnyogpISt5nktdy1MHxUDnc"',
  selfLink: 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files',
  items: 
   [ { kind: 'drive#file',
       id: '0B1ka-zLvU5tjc3RhcnRlcl9maWxl',
       etag: '"fk0AzBEIhUhhdZ8fZzKcL1hA5NE/MTQxMDM1MTI0MTkzOA"',
       selfLink: 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0B1ka-zLvU5tjc3RhcnRlcl9maWxl',
       webContentLink: 'https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B1ka-zLvU5tjc3RhcnRlcl9maWxl&export=download',
       alternateLink: 'https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B1ka-zLvU5tjc3RhcnRlcl9maWxl/edit?usp=drivesdk',
       iconLink: 'https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/doclist/images/icon_10_pdf_list.png',
       thumbnailLink: 'https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/[somestuff]_ZFIkWw-che6o=s220',
       title: 'How to get started with Drive',
       mimeType: 'application/pdf',
       labels: [Object],
       createdDate: '2014-09-10T12:14:01.938Z',
       modifiedDate: '2014-09-10T12:14:01.938Z',
       markedViewedByMeDate: '1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z',
       version: '6',
       parents: [Object],
       downloadUrl: 'https://doc-0s-b4-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/[somestuff]/0B1ka-zLvU5tjc3RhcnRlcl9maWxl?h=16653014193614665626&e=download&gd=true',
       userPermission: [Object],
       originalFilename: 'How to get started with Drive',
       fileExtension: '',
       md5Checksum: '2f215372c903f401e9e101d1d531e5dd',
       fileSize: '3017667',
       quotaBytesUsed: '0',
       ownerNames: [Object],
       owners: [Object],
       lastModifyingUserName: '',
       lastModifyingUser: [Object],
       editable: true,
       copyable: true,
       writersCanShare: true,
       shared: false,
       appDataContents: false } ] }
```

I'm trying to get a 'children.list' from the folder (whether root or with folder id) -  but this isn't it.  Does anyone have any ideas of accessing a folder list with this approach?

Appreciate your help :)